# How to cast an Enum to an int?

Tags: c#, .net, enumeration

I have a function that accepts an Enum ([The base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx)) as a parameter:

```
public void SomeFunction(Enum e);
```

However I can't for some reason cast it to int. I can get the name of the enumeration value but not it's integral representation.
I really don't care about the type of the enumeration, I just need the integral value.
Should I pass an int instead? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to cast?

Comment: @annakata I would *guess* `(int)e`, which gives "Cannot convert type 'System.Enum' to 'int'"

Comment: @annakata: Sorry I thought I am obvious. Marc is right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Enum` isn't actually an enum... confusing. It is a boxed copy of an enum; still, the following should work:

```
int i = (int)(object)e;
```

(this `(object)` cast doesn't *add* a box, since it is *already* boxed)

Note also that not all enums are based on `int`; this unboxing trick may fail for non-`int` enums.

Comment: If the actual type of the `Enum` is known (e.g. Reflection.BindingFlags) one may cast to that and then simply use that as an integer or long value.  That will work for enum types whose underlying type is no bigger than the type one is using.

Answer (score 13):

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(e);
```

This will work regardless of the underlying storage of the enum, whereas the other solutions will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the enum is stored in anything other than `int32` (say, a `byte` or `short`)

Answer (score 0):

```
Int32 intValue = (Int32)Enum.Parse(e.GetType(), e.ToString());
```